# How can I get axios result first ,then send action ?

Tags: redux, redux-thunk, axios

Here is origin code:

```
export function startGame() {
    return function(dispatch) {
        axios({
          method: 'post',
          url: '/api/actions/game/',
          data: {'game':'start'},
          headers: getHeaders(),
        })
        .then(response => {
          if(response.status===200){
            dispatch({
              type: TYPE.START_GAME,
            });
          }
        })
        .catch((error) => {
            dispatch({
                  type: TYPE.ERROR,
                });
        });
    }
}
```

what I want is I get the api result first, and then decide what next step I want to do (because I have many actions that all call the same api )
my logic is below, but I don't know how to make it work
Please help me

```
export function startGame() {


    let result =  function(dispatch) {
        axios({
          method: 'post',
          url: '/api/actions/game/',
          data: {'game':'start'},
          headers: getHeaders(),
        })
        .then(response => {
          if(response.status===200){
            return {
                "result" : "OK",
                "data" : response.data
            }
          }
        })
        .catch((error) => {
            return {
                "result" : "FAIL",
                "data" : error
            }
        });
    }


    if result.result === "OK" {
        dispatch(someAction())
    }else{
        dispatch(otherAction())
    }


}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure why you can't just dispatch the `someAction` and `otherAction` in your axios callbacks. Why doesn't this work for you?

```
export function startGame() {
      return function(dispatch) {
        axios({
          method: 'post',
          url: '/api/actions/game/',
          data: {'game':'start'},
          headers: getHeaders(),
        })
        .then(response => {
          if (response.status === 200) {
            dispatch(someAction(response.data));
          }
        })
        .catch((error) => {
            dispatch(otherAction(error));
        });
    }
}
```

If you want to define the API calling function elsewhere, you can do this:

```
// In some other file, say api.js
export function startGameApiCall() {
  return axios({
    method: 'post',
    url: '/api/actions/game/',
    data: {'game':'start'},
    headers: getHeaders(),
  });
}

// In your actions file
import { startGameApiCall } from './api';

export function startGame() {
  return function (dispatch) {
    startGameApiCall()
      .then(response => dispatch(someAction(response.data)))
      .catch(() => dispatch(otherAction()));
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much,this is what I want

Answer (score 0):

I would also look into https://github.com/svrcekmichal/redux-axios-middleware  It dispatches another action depending on the result of you axios request.